# What does dataclass syntax do without @dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

With the `@dataclass` property, you can define a class with a struct-like syntax.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int
```

which is roughly equivalent to (it actually adds some more methods):

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a
```

But I found you can also do this without `@dataclass`, but it doesn't appear to actually do anything:

```py
class B:
    a: int
```

```py
>>> B(1)
TypeError: B() takes no arguments
>>> B.a
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: Without the `@dataclass`, `a` is a class attribute. While in a dataclass it would be an instance attribute.

Comment: @rdas, yes that is an important difference. Though it's not even a class attribute because `B.a` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head for a while, I had a eureka moment: type hints are for mypy (or any other type checker) not the interpreter. So, what this does is hint that if you have an attribute `a` in an object of type `B`, then it should be an `int`. It feels a little odd to specify the type of a variable that might never exist, but there are you are.

run mypy on:

```py
class B:
    a: int

b = B()
b.a = "s"
```

et voilà `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")`